# Quote or Non quote deference in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb-query

As an example,either of these will work:

```
db.wands.insert({"name": "Dream Bender", "creator": "Foxmond"})
db.wands.insert({name: "Dream Bender", creator: "Foxmond"})
```

Which one will I use any why?

Answer (score 10):

You can use quotes and never have to worry about when they are necessary.

When you run a query or command from the **mongo shell interface** it is
being parsed by the shell's **JavaScript interpreter**.

Anything which isn't valid JavaScript will cause a syntax error.

For example, **A collection or field name starting without an
underscore or alpha character would have to be quoted.**

So, either of these will work:

```
db.wands.insert({"name": "Dream Bender", "creator": "Foxmond"})
db.wands.insert({name: "Dream Bender", creator: "Foxmond"})
```

Also, this would work:

```
db.wands.insert({"3name": "Dream Bender", "creator": "Foxmond"})
```

But this won't work.

```
db.wands.insert({3name: "Dream Bender", creator: "Foxmond"})
```

So, I find it easier to be in the habit of **using quotes** so you don't
have to remember the exceptions.